# Sql Server 2008 - “multi- part identifier could not be bound.”

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I excute this query in query windows it work fine, but if I create **View** with this query it throw error message `"multi- part identifier 'TP.IndexYear'` could not be bound".

Query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(TP.Outline, 0) AS Outline, ISNULL(TP.OutlineInline, 0) - ISNULL(TP.Outline, 0) AS Inline FROM (
   SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT TP.PltrhPositionID) AS OutlineInline,
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(PPH.EndDate) = 9999 OR (PPH.EndDate >= '12/31/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, TP.IndexYear)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Outline
    FROM (
        SELECT
            PH.PltrhPositionID,
            CASE 
                WHEN PH.Plan1 IS NULL OR PH.Plan1 = '' THEN 0 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan2 IS NULL OR PH.Plan2 = '' THEN 1 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan3 IS NULL OR PH.Plan3 = '' THEN 2 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan4 IS NULL OR PH.Plan4 = '' THEN 3 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan5 IS NULL OR PH.Plan5 = '' THEN 4 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan6 IS NULL OR PH.Plan6 = '' THEN 5 + PP.StartYear
                ELSE 6 + PP.StartYear
            END AS IndexYear
        FROM OdpTools_PltrhPosition PH
        LEFT JOIN OdpTools_PltrhPeriod PP ON PP.ID = PH.PltrhPeriodID
        WHERE PH.Closed = 0
    ) AS TP
    LEFT JOIN OdpTools_CurrentPlanPositionHistory PPH ON PPH.PltrhPositionID = TP.PltrhPositionID
) TP
```

Can anybody explain this strange mystery?

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Comment: Maybe don't use `TP` for an alias on two different levels?

Comment: `COALESCE(NULLIF(PH.Plan1,''), 0)` evaluates to 0 if Plan1 IS NULL OR Plan1 = '' A more concise way of expressing that sentiment

Comment: @AaronBertrand wow it's work, I don't know why in sql server view table with same alias cannot be bound. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow suggestion from @AaronBertrand to remove table with same alias in different level, and it work.

```
SELECT ISNULL(TPA.Outline, 0) AS Outline, ISNULL(TPA.OutlineInline, 0) - ISNULL(TPA.Outline, 0) AS Inline FROM (
   SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT TP.PltrhPositionID) AS OutlineInline,
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(PPH.EndDate) = 9999 OR (PPH.EndDate >= '12/31/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, TP.IndexYear)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Outline
    FROM (
        SELECT
            PH.PltrhPositionID,
            CASE 
                WHEN PH.Plan1 IS NULL OR PH.Plan1 = '' THEN 0 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan2 IS NULL OR PH.Plan2 = '' THEN 1 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan3 IS NULL OR PH.Plan3 = '' THEN 2 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan4 IS NULL OR PH.Plan4 = '' THEN 3 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan5 IS NULL OR PH.Plan5 = '' THEN 4 + PP.StartYear
                WHEN PH.Plan6 IS NULL OR PH.Plan6 = '' THEN 5 + PP.StartYear
                ELSE 6 + PP.StartYear
            END AS IndexYear
        FROM OdpTools_PltrhPosition PH
        LEFT JOIN OdpTools_PltrhPeriod PP ON PP.ID = PH.PltrhPeriodID
        WHERE PH.Closed = 0
    ) AS TP
    LEFT JOIN OdpTools_CurrentPlanPositionHistory PPH ON PPH.PltrhPositionID = TP.PltrhPositionID
) TPA //Change TP to TPA
```